# Авто проверка ПО и автоматическое запускание скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, shell, opensuse

есть следующий скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
    ret=$(ps aux | grep [h]top | wc -l)
    if [ "$ret" -eq 0 ]
then {
    echo "Running x11vnc" #output text
        sleep 1  #delay
    x11vnc #command for run program
    exit 1
}
else 
{
    echo "EXIT. x11vnc already running!"
    exit 1
}
fi;
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как сделать так чтобы данный скрипт запускался автоматически на opensuse и чтобы этот скрипт проверял запущена ли ПО к примеру каждые 5 минут?

Comment: cron всему голова

Comment: `*/5 * * * * username [[ -z $(pgrep [h]top) ]] && /x11vnc #command for run program`  в задание cron

Comment: можешь также помочь как сделать так чтобы данный скрипт еще выводил системное уведомление о том что VNC запущен или пере запущен и эта инфа писалась в отдельный  log файл - @PotroNik

Comment: `...[[ -z $(pgrep [h]top) ]] && { /x11vnc #command for run program; echo "VNC - запущен" >> /log.log; } || { echo "VNC уже запущен" >> /log.log; }`

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста еще подсказать как к этому логу файла и время добавить, а именно напротив каждой записи было время например "22.04.2020 16.08 - VNC - запущен" @PotroNik

Comment: `echo "\`date '+%Y-%m-%d %T'\`: text"`

Comment: @ProtoNik, есть же готовые утилиты, которые для системного лога умеет из шелла выводить.